# Человек, который готовит проект

Tags: лексика, значение-слов

Как называется человек, готовящий проект?

Comment: Проект здания готовит архитектор, проект закона готовит юрист и т. д. А как называется человек, который не соблюдает правила пунктуации, в частности начинает предложение со строчной буквы?

Comment: ПРОЕКТИРО́ВЩИК - Специалист по составлению проектов

Answer (score 1):

Всё зависит от того, какое из значений слова "проект" вы подразумеваете:

**прое́кт**

1. План создания чего-либо, включающий в себя описание, чертежи, макеты и т.п.
2. Предварительный текст какого-либо документа, представляемый на обсуждение, утверждение.
3. Замысел чего-либо.

Для некоторых видов деятельности подойдет значение проектировщик (специалист по проектированию, проектировке; инженер-проектировщик).
Для других — конструктор, лицо, занимающееся созданием конструкций различных устройств (машин, механизмов, сооружений и т. п.) или их отдельных частей.
Для третьих — проектант (тот, кто разрабатывает или защищает проект).
Для некоторых отдельных лиц, возможно, подойдет и значение [**прожектёр**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_fwords/29319/%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%9E%D0%96%D0%95%D0%9A%D0%A2%D0%81%D0%A0) (составитель, любитель прожектов, неосновательных проектов, неосуществимых планов).

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю к сказанному ранее ещё одно значение, которое сейчас является едва ли не самым распространённым. В управленческой деятельности подготовкой проекта обычно называют разработку плана управления проектом. 
В этом случае подготовку проекта выполняет, как правило, руководитель проекта.

Comment: Разработка плана управления проектом выполняется руководителем проекта. Допустим. Но вопрос такой был: «Как называется человек, готовящий проект?»

Comment: @shampar Следовательно, так и называется (в лучшем случае): руководитель проекта. Кальки с английского – "менеджер проекта" и "проджект( )менеджер" – мне нравятся меньше (особенно второе), но так тоже говорят, увы.